# Windows support for discard operation of disk drives

Tags: windows, ssd, filesystems, virtualization, swap

Calling a discard operation by a file system to hardware storage is important for both optimal lifespans of solid-state drives and space reclamation of thin-provisioned virtual drives.

Information about support is readily available from sources documenting Linux, but I have found no similar resources for Windows.

I have provisioned  virtual drives for attachment to a virtual machine running Windows 11. One drive is committed exclusively to swap, and while current operation of the system shows minimal swap usage, I find no indication that Windows has freed previously allocated space through hardware operations.

**How does Windows support hardware discard, such as through NTFS, and   is  support also available for managing the page file?**

Comment: Do You mean Trim?

Comment: @Moab, Yes, I understand both terms have the same meaning.

Comment: Some reading here>>>>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)

Comment: I guess your real question is that whether overwriting / truncating a file in Windows will trigger TRIM before the overwrite / after the truncation. I doubt that you'll find reliable resources since in the case of Windows one can only experiment and find out with some forensic-ish approach, and in such case the result can vary because not all SSD "read zero after TRIM" (and some even *conditionally* read zero). The bottom line is, deleting a file on an NTFS definitely make Windows trigger TRIM, but of course whether it can actually be done depends on the drive ultimately.

Comment: But to be frank, don't worry too much about it. Most drives these days probably won't even write to the same part of the back storage even when you are writing the same logical blocks again. So the same thing is probably sort of occuring behind the scene anyway, as long as your drive is not too full.

Answer (score 3):

By default NTFS issues discards automatically when files are truncated or deleted (similar to `mount -o discard` on Linux); see `fsutil behavior query disableDeleteNotify` for discard-on-delete. If this is disabled, then the "Defrag and Optimize" task will still mass-discard all unused sectors in all partitions about once a month.

Windows recognizes thin VHDs when running inside Hyper-V and probably has slightly special treatment for them (but there's no reason it wouldn't work with other VM software that exposes a virtual HDD with discard support).

But generally the swap area (pagefile.sys) is a fixed-size, **pre-allocated** file, where all updates happen in-place to the exact same logical sectors; in other words there *is* no space that would be "freed up" during normal operation.

There is no point in issuing discards for in-place overwrites – if new data is written to the same logical sector, the disk automatically *knows* that the old data can be discarded because no sector is mapped to it anymore. (That's the same mechanism that prevents SSDs from "filling up" when TRIM isn't being used.)